# How can i use forEach for Json Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

Hi Everyove i have a json array `GelenDeger` is like

```
>GelenDeger
{Localizations: null, Languages: null, AgencyModels: null, GetCitiesModel: {…}, GetCountyModel: null, …}
AgencyAddress: null
GetCitiesModel: {IL_KOD: "35", IL_AD: null, ULKE_KOD: null}
GetCountyModel: null
HtmlResult: ""
M_ACENTE: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
countryCode: 1234
```

and I can get when I click the button

`GelenDeger.M_ACENTE[0].ADRES_TEXT`

and

`GelenDeger.M_ACENTE[0].ACENTE_AD`

but I need a loop and without having to use indexes like `[0]` or `[1]` or `[2]` but I don't know how can to do this. Can you help me on this. Thanks.

My js code :

```
function jsFiltreleme(GelenDeger) {
                    $("#myDiv").append(
                        "<div style='border-style:ridge;'>adress : <strong>" + GelenDeger.M_ACENTE[0].ADRES_TEXT + "</strong><br>" +
                        "name : <strong>" + GelenDeger.M_ACENTE[0].ACENTE_AD+ "</strong></div>"
                    );
                }
```

My html code :

```
<li class="none buttonBox">
    <input id="register" type="submit" value="Search">
</li>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

BTW my JSON array can be changeable like M_ACENTE: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: Can you correct that *"pseudo-json"*? it's horribly mangled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach()` for that purpose.

```
function jsFiltreleme(GelenDeger) {
      GelenDeger.M_ACENTE.forEach(acente => {
        $("#myDiv").append(
          "<div style='border-style:ridge;'>adress : <strong>" + acente.ADRES_TEXT + "</strong><br>" +
          "name : <strong>" + acente.ACENTE_AD + "</strong></div>"
        );
      });
 }
```

You can check if the `div` is not empty and then clearing it.

```
if ($("#myDiv").html() !== "") {
  $("#myDiv").html() = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply make function and pass parameter or argument what you say to like or you can use ES6 function so simply type function parameter name and after that give '=>' then give '.' and what object you stored in your array give name and append your little handy dandy tag thats it not that complicated